# Running function code only when NOT assigning output to variable?

Tags: python, return, variable-assignment

I am looking for a way in python to stop certain parts of the code inside a function but only when the output of the function is assigned to a variable. If the the function is run without any assignment then it should run all the inside of it.

Something like this:

```
def function():
    print('a')
    return ('a')

function()

A=function()
```

The first time that I call `function()` it should display `a` on the screen, while the second time nothing should `print` and only store value returned into `A`.

I have not tried anything since I am kind of new to Python, but I was imagining it would be something like the `if __name__=='__main__':` way of checking if a script is being used as a module or run directly.

Comment: That's not how functions work. They have no idea what happens to their return value. If you want to change their behaviour use an argument. In your case it might be best to do the print outside of the function: `print(function())`

Comment: Hi Aris, could you please explain more what do you mean by "stop certain parts of the code" ? Do you expect the instructions to stop the execution flow, or avoid them?
Anyway I don't think such a behavior could be achieved in python, because within the scope of the function call, there is no indication what your will do with the returned value.
You will have to give a parameter to the function that tells it to skip/stop with a default value to ease the call.
```python
def call_and_skip(skip_instructions=False):
    if not skip_instructions:
        call_stuff_or_not()
    call()
```

Comment: @zesk: I suggest that you delete your comment and post it as an answer—might get some points!

Comment: @martineau: ok, let's do this :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a behavior could be achieved in python, because within the scope of the function call, there is no indication what your will do with the returned value. 
You will have to give an argument to the function that tells it to skip/stop with a default value to ease the call.

```
def call_and_skip(skip_instructions=False): 
    if not skip_instructions: 
        call_stuff_or_not() 
    call_everytime()

call_and_skip()
# will not skip inside instruction

a_variable = call_and_skip(skip_instructions=True)
# will skip inside instructions
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentionned in comments, what you're asking for is not technically possible - a function has (and cannot have) any knowledge of what the calling code will do with the return value.

For a simple case like your example snippet, the obvious solution is to just remove the `print` call from within the function and leave it out to the caller, ie:

```
def fun():
   return 'a'

print(fun())
```

Now I assume your real code is a bit more complex than this so such a simple solution would not work. If that's the case, the solution is to split the original function   into many distinct one and let the caller choose which part it wants to call. If you have a complex state (local variables) that need to be shared between the different parts, you can wrap the whole thing into a class, turning the sub functions into methods and storing those variables as instance attributes.